# Clarifications on GridSearchCV in sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I have the following questions regarding `GridSearchCV` in sklearn. I tried but could not find clear answers.
Below is the code patch iam using -

```
dep = df2['responder_flag']
indep = df2.drop(df2.columns[[0,85]], axis = 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(indep, dep,test_size=0.25, random_state = 23)

train = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic')
param_grid = {'max_depth': [4,5], 'n_estimators': [500], 'learning_rate': [0.02,0.01]}
grid = GridSearchCV(train, param_grid,cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

1. Is `cross_validation` i.e. cv parameter in `GridSearchCV` equivalent to `Kfold` or other CV techniques explicitly applied using `cross_validation_score` and other similar functions when training the data?
2. Can i use `GridsearchCV` for just cross validation?
   say if i do not provide multiple parameter list, will it be equal to a cross validation technique?
3. Once the `grid.fit(X_train, y_train)` statement is executed, does that train the model on the best parameters identified and can be used for model prediction directly or will I need to define another estimator with `grid.best_params_` then train and use that for prediction?

Apologies if these are answered earlier.

Comment: Regarding point 1, what do you mean by `cross_validation` parameter?

Comment: hey, i mean the cv parameter in GridSearchCV; as mentioned in the code : (cv = 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the answers:

1. `cv` parameter is equivalent to k-fold.
   In `GridSearchCV`, we give a set of of param values that we want the model to take. Lets say we take `learning_rate` = 0.0001 from [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]. When we specify cv= 5 in `gridsearch`, it will perform `5-fold cv` for `000.1`. Similarly, it will also perform `5-fold cv` for the remaining values. k in this case is 5.
2. In a sense, yes. But dont do it because GridSearchCV expects a param list.
   `GridSearchCV` is a method for performing hyper-parameter tuning. If you do not specify multiple param list, it defeats the purpose of using GridSearch.
3. Fitting the model with `grid.best_params_` on the training set manually after completing `grid.fit(X_train, y_train)` is not necessary. `GridSearchv` has a parameter called `refit` which will refit the `grid.best_esitmator_` to the whole training set automatically if we set `refit = True`. It is by default set to `True`. [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answers Saurabh! The reason i ask step 2 is coz i was trying to apply cv to xgboost (not the xgboost in sk-learn) and was unable to actually process it correctly using xgboost.cv function. Thought of this as a work around. So if i send a single param list like for example - params_list = {'max_depth': [4], 'n_estimators': [500], 'learning_rate': [0.01]}, it would help just process the cross validation (technically) i believe. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: If you don't need hyper-parameter tuning then `GridSearchCV` is not the way to go, since using the default parameters of your model for GridSearchCV like this, will only produce a parameter grid with one combination, so it would be like just performing only CV. It wouldn't make sense to do it like this - if I have understood your question correctly

Comment: with `cv=5` for classification problem, it will perform `stratifiedKfold` instead of just `kfold`.